# Javascript: If statement - two variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, input, conditional-statements

I am trying to check if level is something and degree is something, then total is a value of certain field. The code only works for Example 1 which makes me think I need degree in the variable.

Examples:

- `level = 1; degree = Terminal; 1_T = 205`
- `level = 2; degree = NonTerminal; 2_NT = 230`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".level input" && ".degree input").change(function(){
        var level = $(".level input").val();

        if (level == "1" || degree == "Terminal"){
          $(".total input").val($(".1_T input").val());
        }
        else if (level == "2" || degree == "NonTerminal") {
          $(".total input").val($(".2_NT input").val());
        }
        });
    })
```

What am I doing wrong? I was trying to figure out if there was a way to define a second variable like on line 3 I did with level there should probably something that defines the degree.

Comment: What's `$(".level input" && ".degree input")` supposed to do?

Comment: Where is the variable `degree` ? As per your statement `if (level == "1" || degree == "Terminal"){` should be `if (level == "1" && degree == "Terminal"){`

Comment: @j08691 I imagine the OP wants to hook up a `change` handler based on two different selectors, aka `$(".level input, .degree input").change(…)`

Comment: I am new to javascript and trying to learn - no reason to downvote my question guys :) I appreciate any help! @ Pugazh that is what I wan't sure about - where to put it. @j08691 as Phrogz answered I need to use a change handler based on level and degree input.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
  $(".level input, .degree input").change(function(){
    var level  = $(".level input").val();
    var degree = $(".degree input").val();

    // Perhaps you want (level=="1" && degree=="Terminal") ?
    if (level == "1" || degree == "Terminal"){
      $(".total input").val($(".1_T input").val());
    }
    else if (level == "2" || degree == "NonTerminal") {
      $(".total input").val($(".2_NT input").val());
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Hi Phrogz, I see what you did there and yes it should be &&. Even with that change it is still not working - selection of any level presets the 1_T value.

Comment: @Nestalna Then you'll have to debug your code. Set breakpoints in the Chrome debugger. Examine values of your variables and compare them to your expectations. Step through your code in real-time and ask yourself "Why is the computer making this choice?" Is there whitespace in your values that makes your strings not exactly the same? Welcome to Stack Overflow, and welcome to software development. Most of your work is learning how to think like a computer, and how to figure out what the computer is doing. Asking others for help, as you've done, is a good idea, but not the only way forward.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and reply Phrogz, I have been at it for days now so I figured I would ask. Troubleshooting is awesome and I will continue doing it, I just didn't know javascript well enough to know where and how to add the degree variable. I will report back when I find an answer!

Comment: If you don't know how to use the Google Chrome debugger, I highly recommend that you read about it and get comfortable with it (especially setting breakpoints, using the console to evaluate expressions, and stepping through code).

Answer (score 1):

you must déclare your variable `degree` or it will fail since if degree is not defined before you use it, its value will be `undefined`.

your code sould be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".level input, .degree input").change(function(){
    var level = $(".level input").val();
    var degree = $(".degree input").val();

    if (level == "1" || degree == "Terminal"){
      $(".total input").val($(".1_T input").val());
    }
    else if (level == "2" || degree == "NonTerminal") {
      $(".total input").val($(".2_NT input").val());
    }
    });
})
```

- line 2: changed the jQuery selector. yours only match the first string -> `".level input"` and then didn't compute if degree was changed
- line 4: we define the variable degree for later use

## why it work with example 1 ?

javascript boolean operation is lazy checked. since your first test `level == "1"` is True at once, it don't care if `degree` is defined or not. but in exemple 2, this first test fail, and your `degree`  variable is not defined.

Comment: Downvoted because the code you wrote will not work, due to line 2. (Also, FYI, the words "declare" and "example" are misspelled.)

Comment: Hi Darius, thank you for the reply - I tried that before posting and it didn't work :( Good idea for the line 2!

Answer (score 0):

when a input value insert you want an event to fire,other input another event,what if input first button appears other button disappears do it like that,each button will fire different event